# Eclipse Standard/SDK Version: 4.7.0 doesn't support openJdk 11

Tags: java, eclipse

I have installed *openjdk*: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64` on my Ubuntu.
I've installed eclipse `scala-ide`:

```
Scala IDE build of Eclipse SDK
Build id: 4.7.0-vfinal-2017-09-29T14:34:02Z-Typesafe
(c) LAMP/EPFL and Typesafe for Scala IDE and associated plugins
```

Eclipse requires jre home, but I do not have any. I do not want install jre in separate way, because of installed JDK should cover my needs. In case I try configure eclipse with JDK, it does not accept changes (because of JRE requirement).

Is there any chance to configure Eclipse with openJdk-11 (how)?

Comment: Are you saying Eclipse doesn't run? Or it does run but doesn't understand Java 11 as an 'Installed JRE'?

Comment: @greg-449. I've configured `eclipse.ini` as it was recommended to make it running (firstly it doesn't). So my eclipse can be started, but I can't configure jre home for it having openJdk11.

Comment: Eclipse SDK 4.7.0 was released in June last year and Java 11 will be released in September. Try at least Eclipse 4.7.3a which supports Java 10 or better the latest version of Eclipse which is currently 4.8.0.

Comment: @howlger Eclipse SDK 4.7.0 requires `JDK 8`. I'm using newer one, also eclipse.ini was configured for it. Eclipse starts correctly. I do not believe that eclipse can't be configured with openjdk11 to recognize it like jre8 for example.

Comment: Eclipse 4.7.0 won't recognise Java 9 onwards. Eclipse 4.8 will recognise Java 9 and 10, not sure about 11

Comment: A JDK is a JRE with additions (`javac`, source, etc.). What happens if you use Eclipse Photon (4.8.0) and configure the preview version of OpenJDK 11 in _Windows > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_? Since OpenJDK 11 does not yet exist, not even a release candidate, this setup should only be used for trying it out.

Comment: You know eclipse needs java to start it. Also it needs more java (jre) to start java apps. I've just used oracle jdk8, and everything became working (eclipse, scala-ide, and so on). I very confused because of this behavior, but solution is to use jdk8. I've used Eclipse 4.7 because of this is newest eclipse version for scala IDE plugin.

Comment: The requirement for Java 8 is as the minimum version.

Comment: Running a Java application with a newer JRE/JDK is not the problem, but if you write Java code based on a newer JRE/JDK, Eclipse must read the bytecode of the JRE/JDK classes to compile your source code. Since Java 9 this JRE/JDK bytecode is stored in so-called [modular run-time images](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/220) instead of in `.jar` files. In Java 10 the bytecode version has been incremented even though the bytecode format has not changed (the types of `var` variables are resolved on compile-time). For each new bytecode version, the tools that read bytecode must be adapted.